# Render partial after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have the following code to execute an ajax call and render a partial:

```
$("#save-category").click(function(){
    var category_id = $('#categorization_category_id').val();
    var category_name = $('#categorization_category_id  option:selected').text();
    var user_id = "#{current_user.id}";
    $.ajax({
      url: "#{dashboard_categorizations_path}",
      type: 'POST',
      dataType : 'json',
      data: {'user_id': user_id, 'category_id': category_id},
      success: function(data) {
        $("#categoriamensaje").show();
        $('.categories').html("#{escape_javascript(render('tutor_categories'))}");
        var leadMessage = setInterval(function(){
              $("#categoriamensaje").hide();
            }, 3000);
      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
      }
    }); // end ajax call
  });
```

everything works except the render partial.

This is the haml code:

```
.row
  .col-md-2
  .col-md-5
    %h3
      = _("Tus Categorias")
    .categories
      = render partial: 'tutor_categories'
  .col-md-4
```

And my controller code:

```
def create
    @categorization = Categorization.new(categorization_params)
    @categorization.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {  render json: {id: @categorization.id.to_json},  success: 200  }
    end
  end
```

Thanks

Comment: Where you have written your js ajax call? Is it .js.erb?

Comment: @RAJ I don't have one, what does this file need???

Comment: Have you written it in `.html.erb`?

Comment: @RAJ no is a html.haml file

Comment: Can you try `escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'full/path/to/the/partial'))`

Comment: there are both in the same path, I have two files, edit.html.haml and _tutor_categories.html.haml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74999/discussion-between-raj-and-jean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion in chat, you need to append new `categorization` records instead of replacing whole list.

Your HAML will become:

```
.row
  .col-md-2
  .col-md-5
    %h3
      = _("Tus Categorias")
    .categories
      = render partial: 'tutor_categories', collection: @user_categories, as: :category 
  .col-md-4
```

Your partial will looks like:

```
.badge-tutor{style:"margin: 2px;"} 
  = link_to "<i class='fa fa-tag'></i> #{category.name} <i class='fa fa-times-circle fa-1x' style='color:#A21F1F;'></i>".html_safe, dashboard_categorization_path(category.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Eliminar esta categoria?' }, style: "color:#fff;text-decoration: none;font-size: 15px;"
```

Controller:

```
def create
  @categorization = Categorization.new(categorization_params)
  @categorization.save

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: {category: @categorization},  success: 200}
  end
end
```

In your AJAX call, you need to update partial rendering code to:

```
$('.categories').html("#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'tutor_categories', :locals => {:category => data.category}))}");
```